# ScriptingBridge for System Events in OSX 10.9.2 (XCode 5.1)

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to use System Events.app via the ScriptingBridge to 'click at' menu (bar) items of running apps in OSX 10.9.2.
Since OSX 10.9 I have a problem creating the header file as it has been described in the apple mailing lists (http://list-archives.org/2013/10/30/xcode-users-lists-apple-com/scripting-bridge-build-problem/f/5557663328).

I thought I found a workaround using the solution proposed for a different context here: [Scripting bridge and generate Microsoft Word header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338454/scripting-bridge-and-generate-microsoft-word-header-file).
On my old MacBook with OSX 10.7 I succesfully created the header file SystemEvents.h as described in the article (without modifying the .sdef file). I added (and copied) the file to my project in OSX 10.9. I could then import the SystemEvents.h file in other classes and then access it via the scripting bridge.

My problem: this only works if I'm running the app from XCode. If I start the application found in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-csqigedweudfzsdvdvcjnrwvorrk/Build/Products/Debug/` the obviously same code will not execute the menu click.

I guess I miss something in my project settings but I wouldn't know what... Any help appreciated! Thanks!