# OBJ-C : Error in opening MIcrosoft Password Protected Doc

Tags: objective-c, macos, ms-word, passwords, scripting-bridge

*I need to add password in Microsoft word, pdf and ppt doc. For that i have integrated  'MicrosoftWord.h' file and used SBApplication.
And used below code to open the password protected doc.
  self.wordApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.microsoft.word"];
    self.wordApp.delegate = self;
    [self.wordApp activate];

```
if ([self.wordApp isRunning]) {
    MicrosoftWordDocument *activeDocument = [self.wordApp activeDocument];

    [activeDocument openFileName:FilePath
              confirmConversions:NO
                        readOnly:NO
                addToRecentFiles:NO
                passwordDocument:@""
                passwordTemplate:@""
                          Revert:NO
                   writePassword:@"1"
           writePasswordTemplate:@""
                   fileConverter:MicrosoftWordE162OpenFormatDocument97];
}
```

But it's giving me below error while opening password protected doc.
**Cannot open Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-1708 "errAEEventNotHandled: the AppleEvent was not handled by any handler " UserInfo={ErrorNumber=-1708}**
Please help me in below two cases.
1. How to open password protected Microsoft word doc using objective-c ?
2. How to create password protected word doc using objective -c ?*

**I Have resolved this, Please read answer.**

Now, I am stuck at another problem.
All I need to create Header file for Microsoft Power Point,Microsoft Excel and Adobe Reader. I have referred below Stack Over Flow Link.

[Scripting bridge and generate Microsoft Word header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338454/scripting-bridge-and-generate-microsoft-word-header-file)

I have created PowerPoint Header file using

```
 $ sdef /Applications/Microsoft\ Office\ 2011/Microsoft\ PowerPoint.app | sdp -fh --basename MicrosoftPowerPoint
```

But it is giving me error while building the app.

**ERROR: MicrosoftPowerPoint.h:3028:2: Redefinition of enumerator 'MicrosoftPowerPoint4006ShapeRange'**

Any one please help me, After creating Header file does it requires to add any script or settings in the app. I need to integrate this module in the same mac app in which i have integrated "MicroSoftWord.h".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have encrypted word doc with password. Below is the solution.

```
- (IBAction)openWordDoc:(id)sender{

NSOpenPanel *openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
[openDlg beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == 1) {
        NSMutableString *fileUrl = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[[openDlg URL] description]] ;
        NSRange range = [fileUrl rangeOfString:@"file://"];
        NSString *filePath = [fileUrl stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"file://localhost"];
        [self openWordDocument:filePath];

    }
}];

}

- (void) openWordDocument:(NSString *)FilePath{
NSLog(@"file Path =%@",FilePath);
self.wordApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.microsoft.word"];
self.wordApp.delegate = self;
[self.wordApp activate];

if ([self.wordApp isRunning]) {
    MicrosoftWordDocument *activeDocument = [self.wordApp activeDocument];


   [activeDocument openFileName:FilePath
              confirmConversions:NO
                        readOnly:NO
                addToRecentFiles:NO
                passwordDocument:@"1"
                passwordTemplate:@""
                          Revert:NO
                   writePassword:@""
           writePasswordTemplate:@""
                   fileConverter:MicrosoftWordE162OpenFormatDocument97];
    activeDocument.password= @"1";

    [activeDocument protectProtectionType:MicrosoftWordE234NoDocumentProtection noReset:NO password:@"1" useIrm:NO enforceStyleLocks:YES] ;

      [activeDocument saveAsFileName:FilePath fileFormat:activeDocument.saveFormat   lockComments:FALSE password:@"1" addToRecentFiles:NO writePassword:@"" readOnlyRecommended:YES embedTruetypeFonts:NO saveNativePictureFormat:NO saveFormsData:NO textEncoding:NO insertLineBreaks:FALSE allowSubstitutions:NO lineEndingType:MicrosoftWordE311LineEndingCrLf HTMLDisplayOnlyOutput:NO maintainCompatibility:NO];

    [activeDocument closeSaving:YES savingIn:[NSURL URLWithString:FilePath]];

}

}
```

Thanks.